# bash command to display a partition label

Tags: bash, label, logical-drive

Which bash command shows the volume label?

Comment: That's not where the answer goes.

Comment: please leave the question section for.. questions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/sbin/blkid /dev/sdXY                    # needs rootpriv for internal drives
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/ | grep sdXY    # workaround for unprivileged users
```

Comment: I like the second line (even without grep)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/527790/list-all-partition-labels

Answer (score 0):

To display the label for the currently mounted partition at `/` use:

```
lsblk -o LABEL,MOUNTPOINT | grep " /$" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Added benefit no `sudo` required.